# Windows 8 Multilingual App Toolkit

Tags: c#, .net, localization, microsoft-metro

So i'm trying to localise my app but the toolkit doesn't seem to be doing anything. I've been following this guide:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj572370.aspx

I followed the guide and when I build I get this in the output:

```
1>  Multilingual App Toolkit build started.
1>  Multilingual App Toolkit build completed successfully.
```

but the .xlf files are empty. I have "English.xlf", "English (United Kingdom).xlf" and "Pseudo Language (Pseudo).xlf" and none of them have anything in it. I do have text in my app, written in English.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong as there is no error message. I also found this guide:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965329.aspx

which doesn't even use the toolkit.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What stood out on the first link is the following fact.  **Language file(s) are empty when initially created. Strings are populated into these files during the next rebuild.**  The second what question, what exactly do you expect to be contained in those files exactly, sounds like you have added any strings thus the files are empty.  I suggest using the method outlined in the second link, it has proven, the very easy to work with in my experience.

Comment: Yeah, I've rebuilt and built again but they're still empty. I have no idea where it is meant to get the strings from or how I add them in myself.

Comment: When you say they are empty, you mean, they are no strings for you to define?

Comment: Yeah, there is nothing in there at all & all of the buttons are greyed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Multilingual App Toolkit needs a resource file to work with. Did you create the proper resource file for your apps culture as described in the link [Translating UI Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965329.aspx)?

If you created that file, you need to enter your strings there. On compile the translator will then copy those strings to each of your selected language files.

After that you will then have to:

- translate the strings manually in each file
- use the translation tools
  automatic translation feature (it's good but not perfect!)
- send the file to a translator